# Express $|x|^{-p},\;x\in\mathbb{R^+},\;0.5<p<1$ as sum of $L^1(\mathbb{R^+}) + L^2(\mathbb{R^+})$ function

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Express $|x|^{-p},\;x\in\mathbb{R^+},\;0.5<p<1$ as sum of $L^1(\mathbb{R^+})+L^2(\mathbb{R^+})$ function.

I have been able to show that $|x|^{-p}$ is neither $L^1$ nor $L^2$, but how do I proceed with second part of the question in the attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIv8A.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $|x|^{-p}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ when $p<1$.

It is integrable on $[1,\infty)$ when $p>1$. That is why it is not integrable on $[0,\infty)$ for any value of $p$.

Similarly it is in $L^2[0,1]$ when $p<1/2$, and in $L^2[1,\infty)$ when $p>1/2$.

It should now be clear how to divide the function into two parts, one on $[0,1]$, the other on $[1,\infty)$.